# Is $\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{a}-1\right)+\log \left(-\frac{a}{a-1}\right)}{\log (10)} = 0$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following function, which for all values of $a$ is exceedlingly close to 0:

```
(Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))])/Log[10]
```

However, it does not simplify to 0. Is this failure to simplify to 0 due to a limitation of Mathematica, or is the function truly different from 0?

[image]

Comment: `Simplify[(Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))])/Log[10], 0 < a < 1]` gives `0`. It is not zero for other real values of `a` or for complex values of `a`.  You can also try `Reduce[(Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))])/Log[10] == 0, a, Reals]`, which gives `0 < a < 1`.

Comment: `Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))]  // Exp // Simplify // Log`   yields zero.

Comment: The effect you are seeing on the plot is caused by the fact that plotting functions use finite-precision values for `a`, which result each of the `Log` expressions to produce another finite-precision value, and the zero-ness of this sum depends on things such as rounding inside computation of these values. You can calculate the plot using precise, rational inputs and see that values all all zero: `Table[{a, (Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))]) / Log[10]},{a, 1/100, 99/100, 1/100}] // ListLinePlot`

Comment: Try the plot with the option `WorkingPrecision -> 16`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before this question gets closed, I'm putting Szabolcs's comment as an answer for future visitors, since I believe it solves OP's question:

Use `Simplify` and provide assumptions about the values of `a`:

```
Simplify[(Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))])/Log[10], 0 < a < 1]

(* 0 *)
```

This confirms the expression vanishes for $0 < a < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the standard Mma functions work with the logarithm not really well. You need to help Mma.

Let us first introduce a function `collectLog` which will represent the sum of logarithms as a logarithm of a product:

```
collectLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1a, rule1b, rule2, g, a, b, x},
   rule1a = Log[a_] + Log[b_] -> Log[a*b];
   rule1b = Log[a_] - Log[b_] -> Log[a/b];
   rule2 = x_*Log[a_] -> Log[a^x];
   g[x_] := x /. rule1a /. rule1b /. rule2;
   FixedPoint[g, expr]
   ];
```

and now let us apply it and then let us simplify under the logarithm:

```
expr1 = (Log[-1 + 1/a] + Log[-(a/(-1 + a))])/Log[10];

MapAt[Simplify[#, a > 0] &, collectLog[expr1], {1, 1}]

(*  0  *)
```

Done. Have fun!